# Clear the variables except first row in a group after separate row R

Tags: r, tidyverse, tail

I have to achieve 3 things :

1. Separate rows splitted by Col : "Date" contain different years.
2. **EXCEPT** the Col :"Fix" , only keep **FIRST row within a group** has data.
3. Calculate Col : "Price" in even divided by the the numbers of row splitted.

   ```
   # Dataset call df 

   Name Fix Price   Date 
   Tom  600  500     2016-01-01
   John 800  400     2016-01-03;2016-01-09
   Mary 1100 1000    2016-01-04;2017-09-01;2017-08-10;2018-01-01
   Joe  30   25      2016-01-04;2017-09-01
   Paul 400  304     2015-01-02
   Alex 505  238     2018-01-02;2018-02-02

   # Targeted df

   Name Fix  Price   Date 
   Tom  600  500     2016-01-01
   John 800  400     2016-01-03;2016-01-09
   Mary 1100 250     2016-01-04
   Mary 0    250     2017-09-01
   Mary 0    250     2017-08-10
   Mary 0    250     2018-01-01
   Joe  30   12.5    2016-01-04
   Joe  0    12.5    2017-09-01
   Paul 400  304     2015-01-02
   Alex 505  238     2018-01-02;2018-02-02
   ```

I have an approach to achieve 1 and 3 , but i cannot make 2  that i don't know any the Diverse function of fill().

```
# Find the SPLIT TARGET first :
inds <- sapply(strsplit(df$Date, ";"), function(x) 
length(unique(format(as.Date(x), "%Y"))) > 1) ### This approach actually 
does not works in my actual data when over 1 Million rows , i chunk it into a smaller data 
to fit this approach's limit.

library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

#Select those indices 

df[inds, ] %>% mutate(Price = Price / (str_count(Date,";") + 1)) %>%
separate_rows(Date, sep = ";") %>%
bind_rows(df[!inds,])
```

*Please remind you cannot use Col : " Name " for something as they just represent that the dataset has other values those have to copy by `separate_rows`
How can i clear point 2 ? Its drive me crazy .Thanks for any comments in advances

Comment: I get your philosophy, but I don't get why you separate Mary in 4 rows. It seems you need 3 rows for Mary as the 2017 Dates should be grouped together right? Check rows 4 and 5 of your desired output.  I'll post a solution below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dt = read.table(text = "
Name Fix Price   Date 
                Tom  600  500     2016-01-01
                John 800  400     2016-01-03;2016-01-09
                Mary 1100 1000    2016-01-04;2017-09-01;2017-08-10;2018-01-01
                Joe  30   25      2016-01-04;2017-09-01
                Paul 400  304     2015-01-02
                Alex 505  238     2018-01-02;2018-02-02
                ", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dt %>%
  separate_rows(Date, sep=";") %>%                     # separate dates
  group_by(Name, year = year(ymd(Date))) %>%           # for each Name and year of the date
  summarise(Fix = unique(Fix),                         # keep Fix
            Price = unique(Price),                     # keep Price
            Date = paste0(Date, collapse = ";")) %>%   # combine dates with same year
  mutate(Fix = ifelse(row_number() > 1, 0, Fix),       # update Fix values
         Price = Price/length(Price)) %>%              # divide Price by number of rows
  ungroup()                                            # forget the grouping

# # A tibble: 9 x 5
#   Name   year   Fix Price Date                 
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                
# 1 Alex   2018   505 238   2018-01-02;2018-02-02
# 2 Joe    2016    30  12.5 2016-01-04           
# 3 Joe    2017     0  12.5 2017-09-01           
# 4 John   2016   800 400   2016-01-03;2016-01-09
# 5 Mary   2016  1100 333.  2016-01-04           
# 6 Mary   2017     0 333.  2017-09-01;2017-08-10
# 7 Mary   2018     0 333.  2018-01-01           
# 8 Paul   2015   400 304   2015-01-02           
# 9 Tom    2016   600 500   2016-01-01
```

Comment: Its super awesome , thanks a lot ! To your question , actually there is no specific reason to give Mary additional 3 rows but my limited ability of coding, Main purpose is to split out DIFFERENT year and your approach done perfectly .

Comment: Add Price in mutate for get de mean: mutate(Fix = ifelse(row_number() > 1, 0, Fix),
         Price = Price/length(Price))

Comment: Thank you Juan Antonio Roldán Díaz!